# Why is my interactive chart not responsive on iOS?

Tags: ios, responsive-design

I have a [blog post](http://www.the10and3.com/sports-misery/) that contains an interactive chart. The chart container is designed to be responsive and works well on Chrome, Firefox and Safari for desktop. However, on iOS devices, it does not load as intended. (See the screenshots for how it looks in [portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBEKH.png) and [landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEj81.png). After trying to troubleshoot this with a developer, I have had no luck figuring out the issue. Anyone have any suggestions as to what I can try next?

Answer (score -1):

**Set this property of your webview:**

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: I've been told this is Objective C code and that we need a web solution so this won't help.